# Django ORM query manytomanytofiled to output a list againist a dict key

Tags: django, django-orm

I am going through the trouble query many to field

these are my models

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(
        max_length=200
    )



class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )

    choices = models.ManyToManyField(
        Choice,
        through='QuestionChoice'
    )



class QuestionChoice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    choice = models.ForeignKey(
        Choice,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

I am tring to get all the `Question` with its all choices

My output should loook like this:

```
[
    {
        'title': 'a quetion title', 'choices': [
            {'id': 1,
            'choice_text': 'a choice text example'
            },
            {'id': 1,
            'choice_text': 'another text example'
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        'title': 'another quetion title', 'choices': [
            {'id': 1,
            'choice_text': 'a choice text example'
            },
            {'id': 1,
            'choice_text': 'another text example'
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

I am not getting how to get the output above like this.

I mean, all the choice will be in a list of under the respected dict key choice.

If you closely look at my expected, you will get it.

Can you anyone help me with how to get it done?

I tried with like this below:

```
Question.objects.all().values('title', 'choices')
```

but it returns a repeated time like how many choices it has.

Comment: `Q = Question.objects.all()` would simply get all questions for you .and for accessing **each** question's choices you would have to use that objects `choices.all()` to get related choices for example`Q[0].choices.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QList = [] #This is the final list
question_queryset = Question.objects.all() # This will get all the objects of Question model
for q in question_queryset:
    q_dict = {}
    q_dict['title'] = q.title
    q_dict['choices'] = []
    questionChoice_queryset = QuestionChoice.objects.filter(question=q) #This will basically get all those objects of QuestionChoice model where q is the value of "question" field in QuestionChoice model.
    for o in questionChoice_queryset:
        qChoice = o.choice.choice_text
        choice_dict = {'id':o.choice.id,'choice_text':qChoice}
        q_dict['choices'].append(choice_dict)
    QList.append(q_dict)
```